# PDF reader в Qt

Tags: qt, pdf

Как в Qt можно по нажатии кнопки открыть pdf документ? Возможно ли, открыть pdf документ у тех user'ов, у кого нету установленных pdf reader'ов?

Comment: На ГитХабе уже давно решили вашу проблему:
[Создаём PDF просмотрщик за пару часов](https://habr.com/ru/post/329628/)

Comment: Ну или смотрите в сторону QProcess, к примеру. Вьювер распространять с вашим приложением и запускать его как процесс.

Comment: @lord_marvel спасибо!